# add data to an existing histogram with python

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

As part of a project I'm working on I need to add data to a histogram in a loop. Part of the requirements of the project is that I don't use arrays to store data. Here's the psedo code of what I'm trying to do:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt #could by numpy if that works better

plt.hist(define histogram with n bins)

for i in range (bignumber):
     MCMC to find datapoint
     add point to histogram

plt.plot()
```

The code I'm having trouble with is how to prefine a histogram with no data then append data to it as its generated.

Comment: MCMC: markov chain monte carlo

Comment: Why not using arrays? You could simply create an array with zeros (function numpy.zeros) and increment indexes of that array within the loop. The index number can be determined with something like numpy.searchsorted.

Comment: *"don't use arrays to store data"* is a very strange requirement. Since Matplotlib requires arrays to plot data, it's next to impossible to do it without.

Comment: I have the same problem. Imagine, you have dozens of TB of data and you need to collect some sufficient statistics of the data (which is stored in thousands of files) in a set of histograms to perform further data analysis. There is no way, you can just load all the data at once into RAM and then create a histogram. You can only open one file at once, and keep adding to an existing histogram.

Answer (score 1):

As a bit self-advertisment (disclaimer!)... for updateable histograms, you can use my library called physt: https://github.com/janpipek/physt . After you collect all the data, you may plot the results in a way similar to matplotlib (in fact, using matplotlib in behind).

Comment: This looks like it would work for me. I managed to find a work to my problem  and have finished the project